# Access another system's root folder on mounted zfs rpool

Tags: permissions, mount, live-usb, root, zfs

my Ubuntu instance isn't booting, however I was able to use a Ubuntu Live USB to import the rpool, decrypt the drive, and use the system.key to mount the drive as read-only. I can only seem to access (copy) the files when mounting as read-only.

That said, I need to be able to access one of the folders in /root, but no files or folder are visible in /root using sudo on the Ubuntu Live USB. The particular folder within /root is owned by root and was set with 0400 permissions. I know the folder name and each of the names of the files within it.

Any ideas on how I access this folder to copy the files?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn how Ask Ubuntu works. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Learn what an [on-topic question](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) is. Then take a look to [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.